# Import multiple component with one line (VueJs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vuejs2

I have two projects. One is for creating, writing components and another project will be for rendering them.

So far I have created npm link on componentsProject and liked them in renderingProject

componentsProject
It has two simple components (Clock.vue and TextInput.vue)

Example of TextInput.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea v-model="text"></textarea>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue';

    export default Vue.extend({
        name: 'textInput',
        data() {
            return {
                text: '',
            };
        },
    });
</script>
```

and components folder also contains index.js so I would be able to export them and import them in renderingProject

```
import Clock from './Clock.vue'
import TextInput from './TextInput.vue'
export {
    Clock,
    TextInput
};
```

My renderingProject has following component, which is trying to import all components from componentsProject in one statment

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <Clock></Clock>
    <TextInput></TextInput>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Components } from 'componentsProject/src/components/index.js';


export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'home',
  components: {
      Components,
  },
});
</script>
```

Currently I'm getting following error.

```
"export 'Components' was not found in 'siriusComponents/src/components/index.js'

ERROR in renderProject/src/views/Home.vue
9:28 Could not find a declaration file for module 'componentsProject/src/components/index.js'. 'renderProject/node_modules/componentProject/src/components/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/componetProject` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'componentProject/src/components/index.js';`
     7 | <script lang="ts">
     8 | import Vue from 'vue';
  >  9 | import { Components } from 'componentProject/src/components/index.js';
       |                            ^
    10 | 
    11 | 
    12 | export default Vue.extend({
```

Can you please help me out, how to fix my error, so I could import x number of components with one import statement. If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you!

Comment: Current error is not related to component's import, but to types definitions not provided for imported module `componentProject`. Module type definitions should be declared or set to any (not recommended). [More](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) on modules.

Comment: Can you give me an example how should my syntax look like (declared version) so it would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a solution for my problem.
I changed index.js => index.ts
Code still looks the same

```
import Clock from './Clock.vue';
import TextInput from './TextInput.vue';

export default {
    Clock,
    TextInput,
};
```

I had to change setting in my PhpStorm (Settings => Languages & Frameworks => TypeScript. Check Recompile on change checkbox)

And I made small code change on renderProject, so my import statement looks like this now

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Components from 'componentsProject/src/components/index';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'home',
  components: Components,    
});
</script>
```

And its working! ;)